# Inno setup global install with user-specific settings?

Tags: inno-setup

Inno setup question here...

I'm making a program which should be installed globally for all users, but where each user has his own specific settings for the program, which should definitely **not** be shared. To pull this off in a way which works well in Windows 7, I made the *program itself* create a folder under {userappdata} to store its settings in. However, I would like the setup to be able to do a clean uninstall, which would mean that my uninstaller (ran as admin, of course) needs to delete the folder **for each user that has it**.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do this? I'm stumped...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have the application record the users for which it has created a configuration file, then put the deletion logic in either your main program or a utility application and run it at uninstall-time via inno's `[UninstallRun] Filename: "{app}\WHATEVER.EXE"; Parameters: "/uninstall"`.

Another approach would be to have your main app dynamically append details to an uninstall bat/vbs installed in the application dir and run that.

The only other way I can think of to do this is to use Pascal scripting in the uninstall event.

Comment: Well, the Pascal scripting was actually what I was looking for, but I don't seem to find a way to get a users list, or even with one, to reliably get these folders for all users.

Your idea isn't too bad though. I could put that in the shared user app folder. Maybe I'll do something like that.

I can't believe this sort of issue isn't more common with global installs, tbh.

Comment: Pascal scripting could read an ini file (GetIniString) your app appends to [InstalledFor] \r\n bob=c:\users\bob

Comment: I meant Pascal scripting WITHOUT any changes to the program. Just going over all users, seeing if the folder in appdata exists, and removing it.

Anyway, I implemented the current solution; on startup, the program now adds the user's settings folder to a list in a file nested in the "All Users\Appdata" folder (well, only if it's not in it already, of course). Now I have to wait for the results from my Win7 tester, to see if multiple users can indeed use manipulate that file correctly... anyway, thanks for the help :)